# Why I have to Backbone.$ = require('jquery') in browserify

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, browserify

I am reading [this article](http://learnjs.io/blog/2013/11/23/backbone-jquery-browserify/) and practice it myself.

If I remove Backbone.$ = $, the code will not work. Why?

```
var Backbone = require('backbone');
var $ = require('jquery');
Backbone.$ = $;

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    console.log('wuuut')
    this.render();
  },

  render: function(){
    $('body').prepend('<p>wooooooooooooooo</p>');
  }
});
```

Why in the node js I have to assign jquery to a member in Backbone object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Backbone has this code:

```
// For Backbone's purposes, jQuery, Zepto, Ender, or My Library (kidding) owns
// the `$` variable.
Backbone.$ = $;
```

If you load your modules via `require`, `$` isn't available to backbone, so you have to set it manually. And if you don't, `Backbone.View`, which depends on `jQuery` won't work.

Comment: Since Backbone already has this assignment code, why do I have to it again manually?

Comment: Because of the way browserify wraps its modules, `$` isn't available in global context, and therefore it is not available when `Backbone.$ = $` is called inside of a browserify module.